# Using Django rest_framework_jwt, how to allow auto login with on-time use code?

Tags: python, django, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt

**What I'm trying to do**
Use a link containing a generated code that will login to a specific Django auth_user account without the user needing to enter username and password.

**Current stack**
Django 2
django-rest-framework
django-rest-framework-jwt
django auth

**Question**
Is there a way to get a jwt from rest_framework_jwt without passing it username and password, but maybe just an account reference?

Answer (score 1):

I found instructions on how to generate a token with a user object.
[Create-new-token-manually](https://getblimp.github.io/django-rest-framework-jwt/#creating-a-new-token-manually)

Now I just need the code passed through my link to identify which user I need to obtain and that's it. That can be achieved by extending the user model to store a one-time use code like this. [How to extend auth user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model)